# Not able to install face_recognition module in pyton

Tags: python-3.6

I have python 3.6 installed on my windows 10 when I tried to install the face_recognition module for python I got the following error
it gives me the error when pip tried to install dlib

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib, Click, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3ig35xio\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\dlib'    
         cwd: C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\
    Complete output (59 lines):
    running install
    c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\build\lib.win32-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\build\lib.win32-3.6'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-cljzfpu6/dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-cljzfpu6/dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 159, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cljzfpu6\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension    
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\build\\lib.win32-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\acer\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\build\\lib.win32-3.6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cljzfpu6\\dlib_351488587aea427493530fa6c8e1bf03\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3ig35xio\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output
```

I tried all possible methods to solve this error
by my self
plz help me out of this error

Answer (score 0):

"Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed."

I recommend `pip install wheel`.

Comment: You might want to explain the meaning of the leading quote for the solution you propose and also explain how your solution works and why it helps. If you are not sure that your solution works - or why - you can consider deleting the answer, which in that case should be a comment asking for details or proposing an experiment for debugging.